# how to change display and styles of the labels in react-chartjs-2

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I am using react-chartjs-2 and I want the labels to be circular. also I want the chart itself with labels have a display of inline-block so that I get something like this photo:
[[image: the desired design1]

but what I actually get is this :
[image: the design of chartjs-2]

and my code is here :

```
  let _data = data;
                let _backgroundColor = [];
                let _borderColor = [];
                setDataShareholder(res);
                res.value.forEach(item => {
                    let rgb = `${random(0, 255)}, ${random(0, 255)}, ${random(0, 255)}`;
                    _backgroundColor.push(`rgba(${rgb}, 0.5)`)
                    _borderColor.push(`rgba(${rgb}, 1)`)
                });
                _data.labels = res.value.map(item => item.name)
                _data.datasets = [{
                    data: res.value.map(item => Number(item.violationsCount)),
                    backgroundColor: _backgroundColor,
                    borderColor: _borderColor,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }];
                setData(_data);
```

usage :

```
  import { Doughnut } from 'react-chartjs-2';

  <Doughnut data={data} />
```

please help me if you can. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure the chart options. You can set the legend position to right and pointStyle to circle:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: 'right',
        labels: {
          usePointStyle: true,
          pointStyle: 'circle'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not chart.js it is react-chart.js-2 and I think the usage is diffrent

Comment: No its not, its still chart.js, even in react-chart.js-2 you have an options object where you can pass your chart options which are exactly the same since its a wrapper around chart.js

Comment: oh I did not know that. thank you

Answer (score 1):

so with help of @LeeLenalee I finally changed my code to this and It worked perfectly.

```
const options = {
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            position: 'right',
            rtl : true,
            labels: {
              usePointStyle: true,
              pointStyle: 'circle',
              padding: 20,
            }
          }
        },
    }
    <Doughnut data={data} options={options}/>
```

as you can see I just added a new constant called options and made my changes like above